# Basic HTML help needed

Tags: html, css

I simply want the nav bar to stretch to full height.

i'm quite new to html,css and have little knowledge about it. have tried almost every solution on the internet but still nothing.below is the styling and html code.I gave all the parent containers full height.Don't know what's causing the problem. I picked the style up from the internet and understand what most of it does.I don't

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: aqua;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh !important;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: unset !important;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.8em 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 1px -1px -1px 1px #000, -1px 1px -1px 1px #fff, 0 0 6px 3px #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100vh !important;
}

.nav li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 4px #aaa solid;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2em .33em -0.5em #555;
}

.nav>li:hover,
.nav>li:hover>a {
  border-bottom-color: orange;
}

.nav li:hover>a {
  color: orange;
}

.nav>li:first-child {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.nav>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}

.nav>li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
}

.nav li li a {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.nav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
}
/* submenu positioning*/

.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -99999em;
}

.nav>li:hover>ul {
  left: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.nav>li li:hover>ul {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  top: -1px;
}
/* arrow hover styling */

.nav>li>a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border-top-color: #aaa;
}

.nav>li:hover>a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: orange;
  margin-top: -5px
}

.nav li li>a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border-left-color: #aaa;
  margin-top: -5px
}

.nav li li:hover>a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: orange;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Resume</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item a lonng submenu</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">item</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Ray</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Veronica</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bushy</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Havoc</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Rants</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>




    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly you want? Please add some more details.

Comment: The combination of many of your styles doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Do you want a vertical menu? Please be more specific so we can help you :)

Comment: I think you want to stretch navigation to full window height? Correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: I want to stretch the menu horizontally to fit the window size. I've tried setting up container height to 100%,100vh while following multiple solution but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

why would you want to set the max height oft the nav element to 100vh? If you want it to use the full width you need to set the width: 100vw; `vw` = "Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport" and `vh` is the height.

a simple bar would be like:

```
<body>
<nav></nav>
</body>

<script>
    body { padding: 0; margin: 0}
    nav { width: 100vw;height: 50px;background-color: blue;position: fixed;top: 0}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to read the question properly. OP is asking about why _height_ is not working, not how to set the _width_, so again, this answer ins't useful.